# Plotting x axis for multiple plot in a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to make a histogram for multiple variable. I am running this code which gives me histogram for multiple variable by class.

```
hist_fun = function(x,y){
  ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
}
```

I use this function on my data set as

```
lapply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], function(x) {   hist_fun(x, df$class) })
```

i get all the plot but im unable to get labels on x axis. i tried using xlab where i pass x but that does nothing.

```
hist_fun = function(x,y){
  ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2) + xlab(names(x))
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this.

Comment: Why not just pass the data frame as parameter in your function ? `hist_fun = function(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a sample data.frame:

```r
# generate data.frame
df <- data.frame(num1 = rnorm(12),
                 num2 = rnorm(12)*2,
                 class = rep(c("class1", "class2", "class3"), 4))
```

Your (slightly modified) function generates the plots, but it will label your aesthetics with the name of the arguments you have defined in your function:

```r
# define function
hist_fun <- function(x,y){
  ggplot(df, aes(x = x, fill = y)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
}
# plot
library(ggplot2)
lapply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], hist_fun, df$class)
```

(Notice that I have removed your function definition inside `lapply()` as you can pass on arguments to your custom function.)

To develop functions that make use of ggplot2 properly, you can use [quasiquotation](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/):

```r
# define function
hist_fun <- function(x,y){
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  ggplot(df, aes(x = !!x, fill = !!y)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
}
# plot
library(ggplot2)
lapply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], hist_fun, class)
```

This will at least understand your `class` argument without throwing an error about using the `class()` function instead of a variable. But we still have the default `x` label for the x axis.

#### option 1: with `aes_string()`

One workaround would be to use `aes_string()` and `names()`, which will use the proper labels:

```r
# define function
hist_fun <- function(x,y){
  ggplot(df, aes_string(x, fill = y)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
}
# plot
library(ggplot2)
lapply(names(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]), hist_fun, "class")
```

#### Option 2: without the apply family

And here's a slightly different solution to your problem without the apply family:

```r
# create a list to store plots
plots <- list()
# select only numerical variables
library(dplyr)
df_num <- select_if(df, is.numeric)
# store one plot for each numeric variable, using aes_string()
for (nm in names(df_num)) {
  plots[[nm]] <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = nm, fill = "class")) + geom_density(alpha = 0.2)
}
# print plots
plots
```

#### option 3: tidy data and faceting

If your numerical variables are the same kind of data, I would recommend using `gather()` to create a tidy dataset, and using a faceting function:

```r
# tidy data
library(tidyr)
df_tidy <- gather(df, key = series, value = values, num1:num2)
# plot with facets
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(values, fill = class)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~series)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with one solution closer to your original code, and another option using a tidy dataset, which might or might not apply to your actual data and expected output.